# convert SQL query in LinQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do I convert this into LinQ?

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM YourTable GROUP BY alarmId, alarmUnit
    )
```

tried so far below but doesn't work

```
 var a= from x in YourTable .ToList()
                                  group x by new { x.alarmId, x.alarmUnit} into g
                                  from x1 in YourTable 
                                  where x1.ID == (from x2 in g select x2.ID).Max()
                                  select x1;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which framework are you using? Linq2Sql ? Linq2EF ? Linq2NH? Linq2WTF? How did you get the "Yourtable" variable (I'm guessing the answer, but I hope you will surprise me)

Comment: instead of getting 83 records  I am getting 8556 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a= from x in YourTable .ToList()
       group x by new { x.alarmId, x.alarmUnit} into g
             select new
             {
               alarmId = g.Key.alarmId,
               alarmUnit = g.Key.alarmUnit,
               id = g.Max(b => b.id)
             };
```

Comment: This is working somewhat, I am getting one record from each group however record with lowest Id is being selected instead of record with max Id among group?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = from x in YourTable
        where (
            from y in YourTable
            group y by new { y.alarmId, y.alarmUnit } into g
            select g.Max(z => z.ID)
        ).Contains(x.ID)
        select x;
```

This should yield following SQL

```sql
SELECT [t0].[ID] AS [ID], [t0].[alarmId] AS [alarmId], ...
FROM [YourTable] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX([t1].[ID]) AS [value]
        FROM [YourTable] AS [t1]
        GROUP BY [t1].[alarmId], [t1].[alarmUnit]
    ) AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[value] = [t0].[ID]
)
```

The *exists* in this case is equivalent to *in*. Also, if the ID field is not a key, it will return all records with matching max ID, per your original question.